# Django + fcgi = new edits to views.py not shown

Tags: python, django, apache, fastcgi

I wanted to dive into Python\Django development and used what I had at hands:

- hosting on Hostgator (not a vps but shared).

They do support Django but through fcgi. I did all what was said in the small guide [here](http://support.hostgator.com/articles/django-with-fastcgi)

So I got "hello world" working. Though I have a time instead of hello world in my app's views.py:

```
from datetime import datetime
from django.http import HttpResponse
def index(request):
 return HttpResponse(datetime.now().strftime('%H:%M:%S'))
```

But now, when I do any changes to views.py - i can't see resutls immidiately. I do delete all *.pyc files, still nothing. For example even if do this:

```
return HttpResponse('Hello World!')
```

I don't get this but still see time.

I'm totaly lost already. I tried many things through ssh with django-admin.py...but still - I see time.

If I make a mistake in a code - it will catch it up quick (may be not immidiately) and give out error\debug info, but even after that if I correct it to a new code = still the result is time.

Seems like I'm missing something. Some "refresh" function of views.py...Purge cache..or smth like that? Restart app?

UPD: kill -USR1 index.fcgi   did it!

Comment: apply these changes you need to restart the application by command

Comment: If you solved the problem, either accept the correct answer, or add your own answer containing the solution. Don't modify your title to say "Solved".

Comment: No problem. It's easy enough to miss. But now you know. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the fcgi!

You probably have to restart the spawned server, so it reloads the Python files.

You can achieve that by touching the .fcgi file:

```
$ touch index.fcgi
```

See [How to use Django with FastCGI, SCGI, or AJP](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/fastcgi/#restarting-the-spawned-server).

Dreamhost, a Hostgator competitor says that you sometimes need to [kill the process](http://wiki.dreamhost.com/FastCGI#Errors_and_Troubleshooting):

```
killall -USR1 index.fcgi
```

But I don't know if that works with hostgator too.

Comment: Andre,  thanks! Though it worked now once, and not working further:(

Comment: that's what i do:( is there any other way to restart the app?

Comment: you could rename the index.fcgi to index_old.fcgi see if it breaks (error 500) and then rename it back. But touching it, should actually do the same.

Comment: Renaming - brings me to error 500. Renaming back - give me again an old version.  Is there any kind of cache in django? or apache is doing something tricky?

Comment: Checked if touch does change anything = works. I'm so puzzled by this. Please be sure that I do follow all steps mentioned in guides and what you are saying and I double checked if I'm not missing something. But still - it feels like django caches my compiled app somewhere and rechecks it with some interval or something. <-- wild guess

Comment: killall -USR1 index.fcgi   <- WORKS! \0/  Thank you for all your advice and this info!